# Accept direct credit card payments with PayPal, without incurring PCI compliance issues?

Tags: stripe-payments

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/), using its stripe.js library, will exchange customer credit card information in a payment form for a token using javascript, entirely on the client. Our server never sees the credit card, only the token. As a result, we can avoid PCI compliance issues on our servers and still do direct credit card transactions.

**Does PayPal offer any product that similarly allows me to directly charge customer cards, without incurring PCI compliance requirements on my servers?**

Note: I see that PayPal offers a [vault API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#vault) to exchange credit card numbers for tokens. However, this API itself requires an OAuth bearer token that must be kept as a server secret, not to be shared with browser clients. Therefore, the CC# must travel to our servers for the vault API call to be issued, and therefore incurs PCI compliance requirements on those servers. I wonder, is it perhaps possible to generate an OAuth token that only has permissions to write new credit cards into the vault? I could then give this limited-scope bearer token to a javascript client library, and call it from the client, effectively replicating what stripe.js does.

(Context for the question: we need to accept PayPal due to customer demand, but also want to accept credit cards directly. I either need to use Stripe and write my payment processing code twice for two separate integrations, or I need to find a solution via PayPal that doesn't involve PCI compliance, as that is a headache I definitely want to avoid.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about PayPal services and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. Use of PayPal APIs is on-topic; questions about availability of particular services should be directed to PayPal support via email.

Comment: Personally I'd look at Braintree which will give you client-side API's similar to Stripe.js and Stripe Checkout, and has built in support for Paypal.

Comment: I would argue this is a question about the capabilities of the PayPal API, but I see your point. I could reword the question to talk about APIs instead of products without materially changing it's intent...

Comment: Don't believe they have such. We implemented paypal express, paypal adaptive and paypal direct. I believe the last one requires PCI as CC is sent to server (I'll check with developer on that). Here are our implementations: https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/tree/master/PLATFORM/Modules/PaymentGateways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process described above is called client side tokenization. PayPal does support tokens, but not for credit card data and thus you can't capture credit card info on your own page without PCI. Seems kinda odd that PayPal is one of the few major credit card processors that doesn't support it.

Comment: This is the conclusion I was coming to from my research, but as you said, it just seemed hard to believe so I wanted to ask others with more experience with PayPal. Oh well! Hopefully PayPal catches up soon. Thanks

Comment: We have some contacts in PayPal, so going to check with them and post back here. It should be available, who goes through PCI nowadays.

Comment: Paypal purchased Braintree which supports credit card payments with client side tokenization as well as Paypal purchases in a single API. (Paypal's developer docs now point to the V.Zero API which is Braintree to handle client side tokenization)

Comment: Braintree is indeed the solution. It provides the customer with the choice between direct CC and PayPal payment options and handles all information on their servers via tokenization and an iframe for the actual CC input form.